# Properly handled Promise Rejections

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Considering the following code:

**db.js**

```
// Connecting to catalogstore (mongodb)
const mydb = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.db);
    console.log("Connected to Database!");
  }
  catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Database connection error:", err);
  }
};

export { db }
```

**app.js**

```
import { db } from './db';
db().then(async() => {
  try {
    let server = app.listen(process.env.port,
      process.env.host, function() {
        let host = server.address().address;
        let port = server.address().port;
        console.log('App started');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Basically I'd like to start an Express server only after establishing the db connection.

It actually works fine, however I get this warning:

```
(node:29892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Database connection error:
    at catalogstore (/Users/notaris/Workspace/Google/gcp-devops/apps/catalogservice/src/db.js:44:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
(node:29892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:29892) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How can I properly handle that?

Comment: You don't want to mix handling promises in the traditional (`promise.then().catch()`) and async/await `(try { await foo() } catch (e) {log(e)}`) styles. It will make the code less maintainable and harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown by the `db` async function.

The correct way to handle this `Error` (using an async function/arrow) is:

```
import { db } from './db';
const main = async () => {
  try {
    await db();
    let server = app.listen(process.env.port,
      process.env.host, function() {
        let host = server.address().address;
        let port = server.address().port;
        console.log('App started');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
main();
```

Comment: This is good because you are handling errors consistently using try/catch instead of mixing `.catch()` and try/catch

Answer (score 1):

Modify app.js like follow

```
import { db } from './db';
db()
  .then(/* normal logic */)
  .catch(/* error logic */)
```

Just catch it ^^

Answer (score -1):

In debugger i see that you should catch the error in the promise like this :

```
//app.js
import { db } from './db';
db().then(async() => {
  try {
    let server = app.listen(process.env.port,
      process.env.host, function() {
        let host = server.address().address;
        let port = server.address().port;
        console.log('App started');
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}).catch(error=>{
     console.log('error'+error);
});
```

And you can check this [link](https://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html) for more details.